# Highcharts: completely custom label positions on x-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, histogram, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a histogram using highcharts, but the data is being bucketed by the server so as far as I can tell, I can't use the histogram chart type.

Here's my chart:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    labels: {
      rotation: -45
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: 'variwide',
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [
        { name: '0.00 - 10.10', y: 13, z: 1260000 },
        { name: '10.10 - 34.14', y: 10, z: 3000000 },
        { name: '34.14 - 54.56', y: 9, z: 2550000 },
        { name: '54.56 - 71.43', y: 15, z: 2110000 },
        { name: '71.43 - 102.09', y: 4.6, z: 3830000 },
        { name: '102.09 - 161.56', y: 1.8, z: 7430000 },
        { name: '161.56 - 217.26', y: 5.7, z: 6960000 },
        { name: '217.26 - 301.65', y: 0.7, z: 10550000 },
        { name: '301.65 - 382.82', y: 2.8, z: 10150000 },
        { name: '382.82 - 874.80', y: 0.2, z: 61500000 }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
#container {
 max-width: 800px;
 min-width: 380px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/variwide.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

As you can see, the labels look pretty bad.

Two solutions, neither of which I can work out how to do:

- Rename the points (I can do this) and move them to the right so that they're under the ticks
- Better solution: make the x axis linear and have the labels appear in natural places like they would usually on a linear graph, similar to https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram . Changing the axis to linear seems to mess everything up on a variwide chart, though…

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you thought about giving the labels more rotation?: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ej94a32y/

Comment: yeah, that's not ideal though

Comment: Could you describe how do you expect the labels to behave and look when they're tightly packed?

Comment: @KamilKulig basically like this https://www.highcharts.com/demo/histogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variwide series **doesn't support** non categorized x axis. It's reported as an issue on github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7359

---

**Workaround:**

Variwide can be simulated by using column series.

Create a separate series for each point and link them together by putting `linkedTo: ':previous'` in each of them (except of the first one). Then set `pointRange` for every series. `pointRange` is series' property and cannot be assigned to individual points - that's why separate series has to be crated for each point.

```
  series: [{
    data: [
      [5, 99]
    ],
    pointRange: 2
  }, {
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    data: [
      [7.5, 72]
    ],
    pointRange: 3
  }, {
    linkedTo: ':previous',
    data: [
      [14, 111]
    ],
    pointRange: 10
  }]
```

x position of the point indicates the middle of the column. So if the `x` = 5 and `pointRange` = 2 then the column will span from 4 to 6.

Unfortunately Highcharts doesn't handle extremes well while using multiple values of `pointRange`. Setting x axis minimum fixes it:

```
  xAxis: {
    min: 9, // 4 (axis' minimum) + 10 (max point range) / 2 = 9
  },
```

These `plotOptions` are required to achieve proper widths of columns:

```
  grouping: false,
  groupPadding: 0,
  pointPadding: 0,
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/27gr3wh8/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/